# How to remove thumbnail sizes for specific post type on a child theme?

Tags: custom-post-types, child-theme, post-thumbnails

The theme I'm using includes a slideshow that generates an additional 4 image sizes for every image that is uploaded. I don't need to have all those images being generated for every image.

Is there a way to remove the slideshow thumbnail sizes for a custom post type in my child theme?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be possible, try adding this to your child theme's functions.php

```
 add_action('init', 'remove_plugin_image_sizes');

function remove_plugin_image_sizes() {
    remove_image_size('image-name');
}
```

Here is the documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_image_size

Comment: To be honest, I can't remember even asking this question three years ago. I looked it up, and that function was added a year later.

Comment: haha no worries, just saw this question was related to another question I was looking at. May help people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. I've been searching for something like this as well and haven't come up with a solution. Here is a post I found that may get you headed in the right direction: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-set-different-thumbnail-sizes-per-custom-post-type

Comment: It's starting to look like it's not possible. It's a shame to have to create all those versions ov every image.