# Post thumbnail size for custom field only

Tags: custom-field, post-thumbnails

I'm using advanced custom fields (the plugin), and I have some image upload fields. The images that I'm uploading via this custom field need to have a specific size, but I don't want to create images with this dimensions on every image that is uploaded elsewhere. I just don't want to have hundreds of images being generated that are never going to be used.

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe there is any way around this. I agree it's inefficient, and one of the flaws currently in WP.

Comment: What is the real difference to [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98629/how-to-remove-thumbnail-sizes-for-specific-post-type-on-a-child-theme)?

Comment: @toscho One is about custom fields, and one for post types. Also, the other question is about removing sizes, this one is about adding. I think this is a harder question, the other one may have an answer.